# Parameter optimization using a regression model.

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, regression

I am working on an optimization problem. I build a regression model to understand the behavior of a system which depends on two variables which are functions of another two variables. My regression model is as follows

$Time$ =$\alpha_1$.$M$ + $\alpha_2$.$L$ + $\eta$

Now I know that $M$=$f(N,BW)$ and $L$=$f(N,Const)$

$Const$ is something we can't change and always exist within the system.
My goal is to find $N$ and $BW$ in order to minimize $Time$ for a given $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. Under the following Constraints:

1.$N$ can be a positive whole numbers where $N<=N_{max}$.

2.$BW$ can be any positive number where $BW<=BW_{max}$.

I computed $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ for an arbitrary $N$ and $BW$ but don't have idea how to find the optimal values for $N$ and $BW$.

Any help is much more appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know, what kind of functions the functions (linear, quadratic, etc), $f(N,BW)$ and $f(N,Const)$, are ?

Comment: calculus, The sad thing is I don't know what kind of functions $f(N,BW)$ and $f(N,Const)$ are.But I would guess it's possible to build a linear regression model which can relate $M$ to $N$ and $BW$ ; $L$ to $N$. But I'm not sure. May be a quadratic function would be a better fit. It would be best if it's possible to find optimal values of $N$ and $BW$ without any prior knowledge of the functions.Thanks for your time though.

Comment: If you do not know what kind of fuctions M and L are, then there is no other opportunity to make an assumption of them-in my opinion. Then calculate for different kinds and see, which kinds of function fit best.

Comment: calculus,could you please provide a solution if the functions are linear. In order to reduce system complexity, we often consider linear model.

Comment: Do you observe the values of N and BW?

Comment: Greg, Yes, I definitely observe the values of N and BW!

Answer (score 0):

It could look  like

$$\underset{N,BW}{\texttt{min}} \ \ \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ T_i- \alpha_1(N\cdot n_{i}+ BW\cdot b_{i})-\alpha_2(N\cdot n_{i}+C )-\eta\right]^2 $$

s.t.

$N\leq N_{max}$

$BW\leq BW_{max}$

$N,BW \in \mathbb N$

n is the number of observations.

$T_i$, $b_i$ and $n_i$ are the observations.

The parameters $N$ and $BW$have to be determined.

Comment: From the question, I thought he meant that $N$ and $BW$ are variables, not parameters. I.e. that $M=\gamma_1N+\gamma_2BW$ and
$L=\beta_1N + Const$.

Comment: @Greg I was thinking a long time about that. She have posted, that she want to find N and BW. That´s why I assumed, that N,BW and C are the parameters. But, if it is the other way round, I agree with you.

Comment: $N$ and $BW$ are variables.

Comment: @marcella But if you want to find N and BW, then N and BW are regression parameters. And what about C and $\eta$ ?

Comment: @calculus C or const and $\eta$ both are something known to us. We have to find only optimal $N$ and $BW$ in order to minimize $Time$.

Comment: @marcella If you do regression you do not minimize the time, you minimize the squared difference between observed time ($T_i$) and the time, which is determined by the model and the values of the parameters.  With your information, the model should be like I have now posted.

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume the linear case:

$M=\gamma_1N + \gamma_2BW$

$L=\beta_1N + C$

Now plug these into your regression equation: $Time = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1M + \alpha_2L + \eta$

which yields:

$Time =(\alpha_0+\alpha_2C) + N(\alpha_1\gamma_1 + \alpha_2\beta_1) + \alpha_1\gamma_2BW + \eta$

In the linear case, it is easy to see that the minimum is a function of the signs on the coefficients on $N$ and $BW$. E.g. if $(\alpha_1\gamma_1 + \alpha_2\beta_1)$>0 we want N as small as possible and vice versa.